# Model constants not available in data migrations?

Tags: python, django, data-migration

I want to change the data format in my model and replace a char field with an int choice. The old field is called `objective` and the new field is called `objective_new`

Here is the model definition (excerpt):

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _

class Timer(models.Model):    
    # ...
    OBJECTIVE_HOSTILE = 1
    OBJECTIVE_FRIENDLY = 2    
    OBJECTIVE_NEUTRAL = 3
    OBJECTIVE_UNDEFINED = 4

    OBJECTIVE_CHOICES = [
        (OBJECTIVE_HOSTILE, _('Hostile')),
        (OBJECTIVE_FRIENDLY, _('Friendly')),        
        (OBJECTIVE_NEUTRAL, _('Neutral')),
        (OBJECTIVE_UNDEFINED, _('Undefined')),
    ]
    objective_new = models.SmallIntegerField(
        choices=OBJECTIVE_CHOICES,
        default=OBJECTIVE_UNDEFINED,
        verbose_name='objective',
    )
    objective = models.CharField(
        max_length=254,
        default="",
        blank=True,
        help_text='This field is no longer in use',
    )
    # ...
```

To convert the existing data to the new format I want to use a data migration that maps the text from the old field to the new choice field.

And here is my problem: It seams that the model class that I get in the data migration does not contain any constants, e.g. `OBJECTIVE_CHOICES` which I need to make the mapping.

Here is my data migration code (excerpt):

```
def migrate_forward(apps, schema_editor):
    Timer = apps.get_model('timerboard', 'Timer')
    objective_map = {x[1]: x[0] for x in Timer.OBJECTIVE_CHOICES}
    # ...
```

I am getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: type object 'Timer' has no attribute 'OBJECTIVE_CHOICES'
```

Of course I could just copy the choices definition to my data migration script, but I would rather not want to redefine it in two places. Am I missing something or are class constants like `OBJECTIVE_CHOICES` just in general not available within a data migration?

This is for Django 2.2.

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/migrations/#historical-models which explains why this is. The documentation talks primarily about model methods, but the same applies to class constants as well.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that this applies to class constants as well.